# How do I add a meta tag to the page template from a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a meta tag like this one:

```
<meta name="key" content="value" />
```

to some of the pages in WordPress. I know, I can add this into my template and it will show up. But the thing is, **I am not allowed to even touch the template. It's totally template independent.**

So, I have to add the meta tag only by doing something in my plugin code. I have tried `wp_head` action hook, but it is not working. Is there a workaround or anything to get the meta tag inside the head tags of the pages dynamically?

### What I'm doing

What I'm doing is a little different. There are two pages in my blog, the main content page and *Summary* page. Both of these pages get data through shortcodes. So, the main content page has a shortcode

```
[mainpage]
```

And the *Summary* has this shortcode in it:

```
[summarypage]
```

The shortcode was added to main plugin file

```
add_shortcode( 'mainpage', 'mainPage' );
add_shortcode( 'summarypage', 'summaryPage' );
```

Now, in my plugin directory, I have two PHP files named `mainpage.php` and `summarypage.php`, and they return HTML content.

In mainpage.php

```
function mainPage() {
    // Code which generates HTML content
    $mainpage .= 'content';
    return $mainpage;
}
```

Similarly, in summarypage.php

```
function summaryPage() {
    // Code which generates HTML content
    $summarypage .= 'content';
    return $summarypage;
}
```

Since, $mainpage and $summarypage contains all that which go inside the page textarea box. I have no idea how to add some meta information to my main or summary pages. Using `wp_head` inside the function `mainPage()` and `summaryPage()` doesn't work and rightly so.
So, how can I get a meta tag inside the head section of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could help you better, if you showed us what you have tried already.
Here is a working example:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: No automagic phone numbers
Description: Adds <meta> elements to the <head> to prevent the Skype toolbar and the iPhone from autolinking.
Version: 0.1
Author: Thomas Scholz
Author URI: http://toscho.de
Created: 01.04.2010
*/

if ( ! function_exists('no_automagic_phone_numbers') )
{
    function no_automagic_phone_numbers()
    {
        /* Prevent the Skype plugin and the iPhone from randomly parsing numbers
         * as phone numbers: */
        ?>
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <?php
        if ( ! is_single() and ! is_page() )
        {
            // execute archive stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // single page stuff
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'no_automagic_phone_numbers');
}
```

Now I'm wondering why you are allowed to install plugins but not to change the theme … :)

Comment: the client has such requirements...can't help it!

Comment: Where I output the HTML directly you could check for is_single() or is_page() and echo mainPage();. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: How will chekcking for is_single() or is_page() help me to add the <meta> tag. Please explain!

Comment: wow! thanx man! I've implemented the above code, and it works exactly like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on something similar to

```
function addmeta()
{

  echo "\t<meta name='keywords' content='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' />\n";

}

function shortcodeTemplate($atts) //SHOWS THE SHORTCODE AND RENDERS THE VIEW MODE FOR THE GIVEN VIEW ID
{
 add_action('wp_head', 'addmeta');
echo showTemplate($atts['id']);
}
```

The shortcode Template is being called to render to shortcode.... that is in a post.

Comment: Shortcodes must return a string, they cannot use `echo` or `print`.